# Dependency injection in a loop

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

What is the correct way to do the below so that `ParentClass` isn't dependant on `MyClass`?

```
public class ParentClass
{
    public void MyFunction(IList<Foo> foos)
    {
        foreach (var bar in foos)
        {
            var myClass = new MyClass();
            myClass.DoStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

Normally without a loop I'd just inject it in with the ParentClass constructor, but here I need a new instance of it for each iteration of the loop.

Or maybe there's a better way altogether to do what I'm trying to achieve? Perhaps myClass could reset itself at the end of each iteration so that I can reuse it?

Comment: Then why not define an object collection, or just define DoStuff as static as you create new instance and throw them away immediately

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can inject a factory object that creates MyClass instances into ParentClass.

For each loop iteration, you call the factory object so it gives you a new instance of MyClass.

Comment: How do you create object inside the factory when object has further dependency? In this case, we have to inject the container itself to the factory. I see two caveats here - injecting container and using container.Resolve (service locator). Is this recommended? Any other approach?

Comment: This is a good question, @hungryMind, I think you should promote it as a real question in SO and link it to this one. Anyway, I've found this article that provide some options: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory/

Answer (score 2):

You can inject a `Func<IMyClass>` in the constructor, then call it as many times as you want to get different instances.

IoC frameworks like Autofac support this natively.

Comment: I aggree with you. I would however suggest not to use any IoC container until it becomes required :  DTSTTCPW (Do The Simplest Think That Can Possibly Work)

Comment: @Skyp  'Simplest' is a vague concept without having objectives or goals. If unit testing is a goal, then using IoC is one of the simplest things that could possible work.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want to do with MyClass. As it stands, there is no correlation between foo's, bar's and MyClass. Assuming you would to either inject bar into the Ctor of MyClass, or pass it as a parameter to DoStuff, then I would simply inject a factory class or method into the ParentClass Ctor and use that in place of new-ing up MyClass.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed injection is readable, understandable and easy to verify for correctness.

Resetting the object is an option if the loop is large or if `MyClass` is expensive to create (e.g. it opens a connection, file handle, subprocess or starts a thread).

Since the `reset()` solution takes more time and concentration to verify on each code change, I recommend actually measuring that this is a bottleneck before bothering.